# "Canceled" order because of "Failed merchant rule check" - how to resubmit?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, paypal, magento-1.6, transaction

We had a user submit a large order that exceeded our Paypal security settings for a maximum transaction amount. I have fixed that setting and want to re-submit the order so it charges the user without them having to start a new cart.

Do I click "reorder"?

I want there to be little user interaction so I don't lose this sale. They have already been contacted and want the order to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

appears there is no way to do this from within magento as copying the order/reordering/editing doesnt preserve credit card info.

From PayPal though I am able to bring up the canceled transaction and click "Create reference transaction" and resubmit a sale for the same amount. I will then reorder in magento, mark as paid (captured offline).